# Selecting multiple files for input and getting respective output

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I have this bit of code, which clips out a shapefile of a tree out of a Lidar Pointcloud. When doing this for a single shapefile it works well.

What I want to do: I have 180 individual tree shapefiles and want to clip every file out of the same pointcloud and save it as a individual .las file.
So in the end I should have 180 .las files. **E.g. Input_shp: Tree11.shp -> Output_las: Tree11.las**

I am sure that there is a way to do all of this at once. I just dont know how to select all shapefiles and save the output to 180 individual .las files.

Im really new to Python and any help would be appreciated.

I already tried to get this with placeholders (.format()) but couldnt really get anywhere.

```
from WBT.whitebox_tools import WhiteboxTools

wbt = WhiteboxTools()

wbt.work_dir = "/home/david/Documents/Masterarbeit/Pycrown/Individual Trees/"
wbt.clip_lidar_to_polygon(i="Pointcloud_to_clip.las", polygons="tree_11.shp", output="Tree11.las")
```

Comment: You can easily iterate over the content of a directory using the `os` module with `os.listdir()`. Then you can just call a function that does what you want on one file and call it on every file in the list. If the output filename can be derived from the input name this should be no problem: `for filename in os.listdir(): f(filename)`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I don't have the plugin you are using, but you may be looking for this code snippet:

```
from WBT.whitebox_tools import WhiteboxTools

wbt = WhiteboxTools()

workDir = "/home/david/Documents/Masterarbeit/Pycrown/Individual Trees/"
wbt.work_dir = workDir

# If you want to select all the files in your work dir you can use the following.
# though you may need to make it absolute, depending on where you run this:
filesInFolder = os.listDir(workDir)
numberOfShapeFiles = len([_ for _ in filesInFolder if _.endswith('.shp')])

# assume shape files start at 0 and end at n-1
# loop over all your shape files.
for fileNumber in range(numberOfShapeFiles):
    wbt.clip_lidar_to_polygon(
        i="Pointcloud_to_clip.las",
        polygons=f"tree_{fileNumber}.shp",
        output=f"Tree{fileNumber}.las"
    )
```

This makes use of [python format string templates](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings).
Along with the [os.listdir](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.listdir) function.